# System files missing after copying an SD card in OS X

Tags: macos, clone, sd-card, file-transfer, cloning

I copied all my files from a 4 GB to a 16 GB SD card via OS X Finder, and lost quite a bit of system files that my Android can't find. Is there a trick to get everything to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Finder does not display files beginning with a `.`, for example a `.config` directory or some such. To copy all the files, open Terminal.app, and enter `cp -R /Volumes/4gig/android/ /Volumes/8gig/new`, replacing the file paths with those you actually want to copy. The `-R` stands for recursive, copying the source directory and all subdirectories.